# Mediawiki replacing "Index.php" with info about the wiki

Tags: discord, mediawiki

With mediawiki, it does embed text on discord if you send a link to your wiki.
[image: Mediawiki discord embed]

How would I change this text to have a description, possibly adding an image or removing the embed completely.

EDIT: Wikipedia has achieved this
[image]

Comment: What kind of preview would you expect for Special:AdminLinks?

Comment: @Tgr probably just a description about the wiki

Comment: You can use the [OpenGraphMeta](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:OpenGraphMeta) extension and implement the [OpenGraphMetaHeaders](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-extensions-OpenGraphMeta/blob/807cbe7c08b6353efe7bc3910d4ad6ddf4e9a8d2/OpenGraphMeta.class.php#L152) hook.

Comment: In my experience Discord detects MediaWiki installations and flat out assumes they have Extension:TextExtracts installed, however I haven't checked in a while.